# BitBucket markdown

Tags: bitbucket

do you know how can I generate a TOC for a readme.md file that is store in a BitBucket repository ?

I read some blogs about this, but it's not working proplery, I want links on TOC contents and navigate through document based on TOC content.

Thanks
Sorin

Comment: In the Bitbucket wiki you can add a TOC by putting [TOC] under the title. This may also work for a readme. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-a-table-of-contents-to-a-wiki-221451163.html

Answer (score 4):

Imagine, your document structure would look like this:

```
# Overview
# Features
# Bug reports
# Contributing
# License
```

Bitbucket gives an ID to each of these headings, for example the ID for `# Overview` would be `markdown-heading-overview`, the ID for `# Bug reports` would be `markdown-heading-bug-reports`.

You can create an internal link like that: `[Link text](#id)`, where you replace `id` with the given ID. Your table of contents could look like this:

```
* [Overview](#markdown-heading-overview)
* [Features](#markdown-heading-features)
* [Bug reports](#markdown-heading-bug-reports)
* [Contributing](#markdown-heading-contributing)
* [License](#markdown-heading-license)
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. One remark: in my version of Bitbucket, the ID is 'markdown-header-xxx' rather than 'markdown-heading-xxx'.